# How do I create a voting system in Rails 4 for my blog posts that requires more than two options for voting?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, vote

I have built a very simple rails blog that is based on therapy-like sessions in real life. At the end of every blog post, a user can vote on the post where it says "How does that make you feel?"

I am nearly finished developing the application but I can't figure out how to make an expanded voting system.

There are 6 different emotion options that the user needs to be able to vote with (Happy, Sad, Angry, Inspired, Boring, Anxious). This means that one vote is not in any way better than the other. There are no positive and negative votes. They're just different.

So far, all the gems and tutorials I have come across feature a voting system that consists of two options. I need a way to implement 6.

Lastly, I would like to be able to count all of the total emotions belonging to a particular blog post and display the emotion with the most votes next to the title.

Has anyone ever tried something like this? After I figure out how to do this, I would like to make it into a gem if there isn't already one.

Comment: Roll it yourself.  Make a vote model, that belongs to an user and a post, restrict the vote field to an enum with the desired options.  Build a vote controller around this.

Answer (score 1):

(I'm assuming a user just picks one vote per post, and that you're using the latest Rails 4.2)

Just create a new table that references both `User` and `Post` which has an integer field that we're going to use [the new enum](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) with, eg. `Vote` with integer field `choice`, so the model will be:

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post

  enum choice: %i[happy sad angry inspired boring anxious]
end
```

And your `User` and `Post` models will both `has_many :votes`

Then (as per the docs) you use `Vote.choices` to get a hash of name to integer (you'll use this to populate your view).

...and lastly, you'll get a hash of the count of emotions for a blog post with:

```
post.votes.group('votes.choice').count
```

I'm sure you can pick the most votes in there.

#### Update

The OP asked in a comment where I found this out, I thought my response to him might help others:

> Hmm, well aside from [the docs that I already linked you to in my answer](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html), I follow [the rails-core mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rubyonrails-core) which announces and discusses upcoming features, I follow [@rails on twitter](https://twitter.com/rails) where they announce all sorts of things, I read [the release notes for new versions](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/releases/) and I go through [the release notes in the guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_2_release_notes.html) after major releases.

Comment: There is a problem in your Vote model please make `belongs_to :vote` to `belongs_to :post`

Comment: Heh, actually you made the same error but with the other `belongs_to` - I've fixed it now to be `:post` and **`:user`** :)  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your timely answer smathy! I'm gonna try to implement this now. As I do that, can you link me to where you found this out? For me to study

Comment: Hmm, well aside from [the docs that I already linked you to in my answer](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html), I follow [the rails-core mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rubyonrails-core) which announces and discusses upcoming features, I follow [@rails on twitter](https://twitter.com/rails) where they announce all sorts of things, I read [the release notes for new versions](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/releases/) and I go through [the release notes in the guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_2_release_notes.html) after major releases.

Comment: I got the array to of choices to display, but I need a way for users to select them and POST them to the current blog post. Also, is there a way to make images the way to select the emotions? As in an array of images instead of an array of strings?

Comment: You should probably do a bit more work on it, and then if you're still having trouble you should ask another question with your new issues.